# FAB not anchoring to view consistently

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I'm having issues having my Floating Action Buttons anchor to the views correctly. It almost seems like they're anchoring before the view is measured.

When the issue presents itself, the FAB is anchored to the top left of the screen like:

[image: Error]

And when it works properly:

[image]

The behavior is random, and when it doesn't anchor correctly, it will sometimes fix itself with no user interaction. Other times, it won't correct itself.

Everything I've tried searching for has been resolved by adding the layout_anchor or layout_anchorgravity attributes, which I've already included.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my layout.
EDIT: Had wrong layout originally...

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Place Holder - Stats coming soon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_compare_arrows_white_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/second_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to anchor the floating action button to the top view (i.e, the one with "**placeholder**" textview on it ).

look at cheesesquare project by chris banes on github:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare
 it may give you some idea.

Comment: I had it like that originally, and still had the same behavior. I'll check out the linked project to see if anything stands out.

Comment: I think this is the issue tracker for this unexpected behavior: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221397